# Why is this (image) function transformation not logical?

Tags: functions, coordinate-systems, transformation

I am taking MIT 6.003 course from OCW and came upon the following problem from lecture 1:

[image]

For the above image $f(x, y)$, does the below image represent the transformation $f(-x-250, y)$?

[image]

The correct answer is no but my answer was yes and the reasoning was as follows:

First, we apply the image transformation using $f(-x, y)$ which will result in the original image being flipped about the vertical axis passing through x=0.

Next, we apply the image transformation using $f(x-250, y)$ which will result in the flipped image to translate to the right.

In total, intuitively speaking, applying $f(-x, y)$ followed by $f(x-250, y)$ should result in the 2nd image shown. Can anyone tell me what is the flaw in my logic? I can't figure out why this reasoning **shouldn't** work.

Answer (score 1):

The photo should be toward $-250$ and not $250$ if this transformation is applied, it will be helpful to break this down into smaller transformations
first simply consider $f(x+250,y)$ this is obviously towards $-250$ *now* when when we do $f(-(x+250),y)$ we get a flip and the image is still towards $-250$; Note that $f(-(x+250),y)=f(-x-250,y)$.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that answer, makes sense. Also, could you answer one more question? Why can't we think of applying f(-x-250,y) as the same as applying first f(-x,y) followed by f(x-250, y)? Because if we do, then geometrically the second photo should make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case where translation may go first before scaling. To see why, let's recall that the function $f(x)$ translates to the positive direction when $a > 0$ and $f(x)$ becomes $f(x - a)$, and the function scales horizontally by a factor of $k$ when $f(x)$ becomes $f(kx)$. The special case is when $k = -1$ where it is a reflection.

What you did was reflect, then translate. By checking how that transformations apply, the plane reflects horizontally as expected. The translation part is where it breaks down. You are expecting the plane to be translated to the right (the positive direction), hence the $-250$, but you forgot that the plane was already reflected. This means that it will go to the left, not to the right.

---

See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ylok3f72cb) that I made from Desmos as an example. Note that they are points, and translating it to the positive direction will be to add, not to subtract.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am getting what you are saying. The function f is already reflected by doing -x. So then applying a -250 would translate it to the left instead of the right. But what I don’t get it is that after doing -x, the reflected image is our new f. It’s like we have a fresh function which denotes that reflected image. Now on this new f, if we do a -250, why should it’s behavior be different by going to the left and not the right? Sorry if I am going to much into depth.

Comment: @AvneeshKhanna Sorry for the late reply. I get what you mean now. To avoid confusion, I'll use different names. Let $g(x,y) = f(-x,y)$. Now, we are trying to know what happens when we plot $h$ where $h(x,y) = g(x-250, y)$. This will be your expected result: $h$ will be translated to the right.

Comment: However, what you did was reflect and translate, which reversed the direction of translation. You can try to compensate for the reflection by changing the sign of the translation unit (for instance, $a = 5$ will now be $a = -5$).